How do I associate an .eml file as a text file?
There are some very old and confusing answers on the Internet, so I’m looking for something that works in 2024.
I would like to associate an .eml file as a text file. In the past I could try something like:
assoc .eml=txtfile

That doesn’t seem to work any more. I believe that the solution lies in Regedit with the key Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.eml, but I don’t know what to put there.
I want to save the solution in something like a .reg file to reuse in a classroom.

The easiest method is to simply right-click the file, choose Open With, other program, select notepad and check always open with. After that, you can check what .eml has in the registry and export that.

@LPChip Understood, but I need something which I can automate and reuse

I understood you, which is why I added: after you have made the change, check the registry, and export, so you can automate using that export.

You can also just change the standard default apps list for the extension without going into the registry.

Open Settings.
Choose "Apps" on the left. Choose "Default Apps".
In the box for "Set a default for a file type or link type" enter ".eml".
Click on the program that shows as default and change it to "Notepad".


